# Android bitmap is changing pixel values of edited photo, while saving. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bitmap

Before someone reports this question as duplicate, please know that I have indeed done my homework before posting this question. However, none of the solutions work for me.

Consider the code snippet below for changing certain pixel values in a bitmap image.

```
        int pixels[] = new int[height * width];
        bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        System.out.println("before last "+pixels[pixels.length-1]);
        switch (random) {
            case 0:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            case 1:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.RED;
                break;
            case 2:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            case 3:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.BLUE;
                break;
            case 4:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            case 5:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.MAGENTA;
                break;
            case 6:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.LTGRAY;
                break;
            case 7:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.GRAY;
                break;
            case 8:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.CYAN;
                break;
            case 9:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.WHITE;
                break;
            default:
                pixels[pixels.length - 1] = Color.BLACK;
                break;
        }
```

Once I set specific pixels that way, I finally call `bmp.setPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);`. Once I do that, I even save the image.

However, once I read that saved image and reverse check for the same values,

```
        switch(pixels[pixels.length-1])
        {
            case Color.BLACK : mp=0; break;
            case Color.RED : mp=1; break;
            case Color.GREEN : mp=2; break;
            case Color.BLUE : mp=3; break;
            case Color.YELLOW : mp=4; break;
            case Color.MAGENTA : mp=5; break;
            case Color.LTGRAY : mp=6; break;
            case Color.GRAY : mp=7; break;
            case Color.CYAN : mp=8; break;
            case Color.WHITE : mp=9; break;
            default : mp=0; break;
        }
```

it's completely different! **The error** is that `mp` is always 0.

Based on other internet and forum questions I've gone through, this code should apparently work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use pixel[random]? In switch?

Comment: Not really. My actual code has many more lines and random is used for a different purpose. So based on that random value, I'm storing a color value at the last pixel.